# Capistrano/Passenger deploy failing due to different gem versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, capistrano, passenger, dreamhost

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app to my webhost (DreamHost) using Capistrano but it keeps failing because the various gems installed on the server are of a different version.

I can work around this by manually installing, one by one, the specific gem version when Capistrano complains about it.

There must be a better way.. is there something I can do so that when deploying, it automatically installs the different versions if required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, and it's baked right into bundler...

You just need to add `require 'bundler/capistrano'` to your cap file and all should be fine from then on.

If all is not well you can try `cap bundle:install` manually to clear things up before install.

Comment: thanks. I've just got one problem with that:

bundler isn't installed on my webhost, but I manually installed it and I can run bundle when I ssh into it. However, it isn't able to find the bundle command through Capistrano.

what am I missing?

Comment: By setting the bundle_cmd variable `set :bundle_cmd, PATH_TO_BINARY` you can set the exact path to the bundler binary. You just need to check where your gems are located.